# How to update target from a lostfocus of the source WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have two textboxes in my wpf application  `tb1` and `tb2`.
I want `tb1.text` to be updated with `tb2.Text` **only** when `tb2` loses focus.

I tried:

xaml

```
<TextBox Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb2 }" "/>
<TextBox Name="tb2" />
```

But `tb1.Text` is updated instantly. 
Can it be done using Bindings?

Comment: you meant TextBox?

Comment: This should be handled in the view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the `Binding` is `LostFocus`, so if you choose `tb2` as the **binding target** you can update `tb1` or the **binding source** on lose focus.

Now you want the binding to work in a one-way mode **from target to source** (tb2->tb1), so you need to change `Mode` of `Binding` to `OneWayToSource`.

```
<TextBox Name="tb1" /> <!--tb1.Text is source of binding-->
<TextBox Name="tb2" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb1, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

in case of one-way **source to target** use `OneWay`, otherwise use default which is `TwoWay`.

Comment: That does it but adds an extra binding which is not intended. when I change tb1 tb2 changes.

Comment: @YinonDotan *"adds an extra binding which is not intended"* - why not? That's the way to go. Further, please edit your question because as has been pointed out, currently it's unclear what you're looking for - do you really mean `TextBlock`s?

Comment: Because I dont want tb2 to be updated when tb1 changes.

Comment: @YinonDotan thank you for clarification, I updated my answer.

Comment: That's it nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tb2_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb1.Text = tb2.Text;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia this code is so simple that any explanation will only make it more complicated